# Onclick IOS - не работает

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

```js
function openmenu() {
  alert("THANK YOU");
}
```

```css
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #633f89;
  height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px #633f89 solid;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" onclick="openmenu();">CLICK ME, PLS
</button>
```

При клике с IOS устройства - тишина. Как поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

У `button` по умолчанию не установлен стиль `cursor: pointer`, в iOS может не срабатывать событие клика из-за этого.

**Вариант 2:**
Добавить обработку события `touchstart`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click touchstart', openmenu);
});

function openmenu() {
  alert("THANK YOU");
}
```

```css
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #633f89;
  height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 2px #633f89 solid;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">CLICK ME, PLS
</button>
```

Comment: Я уже добавил курсор поинтер же, или что делать? touchstart - у меня в атрибуте кнокпи прописано событие?

Comment: Тогда можно попробовать добавить атрибут `ontouchstart="openmenu()"`, если вам важно сохранить вызов функции в атрибутах.

Comment: Не уверен что он существует

Comment: Написать комментарий, видимо, быстрее, чем поискать https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ontouchstart

Comment: Не совсем правильно написано т.к. `touchstart = mousedown`, но ни как не `click`